# interpreting jstack output

Tags: neo4j, deadlock, java, jstack

I have a java process loading a lot of data from a bunch of .csv files into a Neo4j database using the `BatchInserter`. I was using:

- OpenJDK 7
- Ubuntu 12.04
- Neo4j 2.0 M3

After loading the first 164 GB (according to `ls -lh`) the folder size stopped increasing but the process kept running, no memory was released, and CPU was still at 100% (all according to `htop`).

The loading process is single threaded, only the JVM is using more than 1 thread - I guess by the `ParallelGC`.

I'm not sure how to diagnose this type of problem but was instructed to try `jstack`, so have included its output below.

**Anyone has an idea what went wrong or has suggestions on how I can go about diagnosing this?**

```
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (22.0-b10 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc3a4001000 nid=0x5636 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58123000 nid=0x4545 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58120800 nid=0x4544 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf5811d800 nid=0x4543 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf5811b800 nid=0x4542 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf580c4800 nid=0x4541 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc3f3cfb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00007fc4165fc708> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
        - locked <0x00007fc4165fc708> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf580c2000 nid=0x4540 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc3f3dfc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00007fc4165ffe08> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
        - locked <0x00007fc4165ffe08> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58007800 nid=0x452c runnable [0x00007fcf606b7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1960)
        at java.lang.String.subSequence(String.java:1993)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1202)
        at com.ldbc.socialnet.neo4j.CsvFileReader.parseLine(CsvFileReader.java:73)
        at com.ldbc.socialnet.neo4j.CsvFileReader.nextLine(CsvFileReader.java:61)
        at com.ldbc.socialnet.neo4j.CsvFileReader.hasNext(CsvFileReader.java:33)
        at com.ldbc.socialnet.neo4j.CsvFileInserter.bufferLines(CsvFileInserter.java:62)
        at com.ldbc.socialnet.neo4j.CsvFileInserter.insertAllBuffered(CsvFileInserter.java:93)
        at com.ldbc.socialnet.neo4j.LdbcSocialNeworkNeo4jImporter.load(LdbcSocialNeworkNeo4jImporter.java:79)
        at com.ldbc.socialnet.neo4j.LdbcSocialNeworkNeo4jImporter.main(LdbcSocialNeworkNeo4jImporter.java:49)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf580ba000 nid=0x453f runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58012800 nid=0x452d runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58014800 nid=0x452e runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58016000 nid=0x452f runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58018000 nid=0x4530 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf5801a000 nid=0x4531 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf5801b800 nid=0x4532 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf5801d800 nid=0x4533 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf5801f800 nid=0x4534 runnable 

"GC task thread#8 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58021000 nid=0x4535 runnable 

"GC task thread#9 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58023000 nid=0x4536 runnable 

"GC task thread#10 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58025000 nid=0x4537 runnable 

"GC task thread#11 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58026800 nid=0x4538 runnable 

"GC task thread#12 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58028800 nid=0x4539 runnable 

"GC task thread#13 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf5802a800 nid=0x453a runnable 

"GC task thread#14 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf5802c800 nid=0x453b runnable 

"GC task thread#15 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf5802e000 nid=0x453c runnable 

"GC task thread#16 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58030000 nid=0x453d runnable 

"GC task thread#17 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf58032000 nid=0x453e runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fcf5812d800 nid=0x4546 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 175

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 11211840K, used 7045440K [0x00007fcb95000000, 0x00007fcf3d160000, 0x00007fcf55000000)
  eden space 7045440K, 100% used [0x00007fcb95000000,0x00007fcd43050000,0x00007fcd43050000)
  from space 4166400K, 0% used [0x00007fce39510000,0x00007fce39510000,0x00007fcf379d0000)
  to   space 4035328K, 0% used [0x00007fcd43050000,0x00007fcd43050000,0x00007fce39510000)
 PSOldGen        total 31457280K, used 31300002K [0x00007fc415000000, 0x00007fcb95000000, 0x00007fcb95000000)
  object space 31457280K, 99% used [0x00007fc415000000,0x00007fcb8b668b98,0x00007fcb95000000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 7487K [0x00007fc40aa00000, 0x00007fc40bec0000, 0x00007fc415000000)
  object space 21248K, 35% used [0x00007fc40aa00000,0x00007fc40b14ff48,0x00007fc40bec0000)
```

In particular, can anyone give a little insight on these heap values or suggest a good read about them?

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 16348096K, used 12660905K [0x00007f833a560000, 0x00007f87639c0000, 0x00007f8765000000)
  eden space 15282432K, 82% used [0x00007f833a560000,0x00007f863f18a688,0x00007f86df1a0000)
  from space 1065664K, 0% used [0x00007f86df1a0000,0x00007f86df1a0000,0x00007f8720250000)
  to   space 1036288K, 0% used [0x00007f87245c0000,0x00007f87245c0000,0x00007f87639c0000)
 ParOldGen       total 34952576K, used 34903343K [0x00007f7ae5000000, 0x00007f833a560000, 0x00007f833a560000)
  object space 34952576K, 99% used [0x00007f7ae5000000,0x00007f833754bd90,0x00007f833a560000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 7130K [0x00007f7adfe00000, 0x00007f7ae12c0000, 0x00007f7ae5000000)
  object space 21248K, 33% used [0x00007f7adfe00000,0x00007f7ae04f6860,0x00007f7ae12c0000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your process is almost out of memory:

```
eden space 7045440K, 100% used
object space 31457280K, 99% used
```

In this case GC may run continiosly, trying to free some memory, consuming alomist all CPU. So application logic thread is under heavy starvation. You may either add more memory via -Xmx JVM option or profile the application. Profiling via JVisualVM, Jprofiler or other tool will give you important runtime data:

- Memory allocaton dynamics. If memory consumption is increasing all the time you're likely to have a memory leak
- Heap contents to find out what occupies the momory
- GC statistics

Based on this data you'll certanly be able to resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks, will keep an eye on those in future. do you know which of the following are most important to monitor? 

Heap *** PSYoungGen (total 16348096K, used 12660905K) -- eden space 15282432K, 82% used -- from space 1065664K, 0% used -- to   space 1036288K, 0% used *** ParOldGen -- total 34952576K, used 34903343K 
  object space 34952576K, 99% used *** PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 7130K object space 21248K, 33% used

Comment: ParOldGen is the most important for long-term memory consumption monitoring. If process has no memory leaks, then it should be more or less stable in the long run.

Comment: thanks again. fyi, I don't think it's a memory leak. the process maintains a number of "large" <Long,Long> maps (~450,000,000 entries in total). I only took these maps into consideration when selecting Xmx and didn't leave much breathing room. now that I think about it I also maintain a number of buffers (String[][]) and other temp state. have now restarted the process with increased heap and will keep an eye on jstack heap info.